# core plot scatter plot text and symbol alignment

Tags: macos, core-plot, scatter-plot

### new to core plot; I have 3 scatter plot questions:

Using the gallery sample scatter plot, I hacked it to add several plots, line-less, each with a symbol - 16x16 circle I color select by plot. I want to lay atop that symbol a 2 character text label (I stole elsewhere here):

```
- (nullable CPTPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(nonnull CPTScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CPTPlotSymbol * symbol = nil;

    symbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:cptSymbols[index % BET_MAXIMUM]];
    symbol.size = CGSizeMake(16,16);

    return symbol;
}

- (CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSString * symbolName = [cptSymbols[index % BET_MAXIMUM] substringToIndex:2];
    CPTTextLayer * label = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:symbolName];
    CPTMutableTextStyle * textStyle = [label.textStyle mutableCopy];

    plot.labelOffset = 0;
    textStyle.color = cptColors[Random(cptColors.count)];
    label.textStyle = textStyle;
    [textStyle release];
    return [label autorelease];
}
```

but the text layering I need to position it center atop the symbol; its color is chosen to contrast with the symbol color. In it's final form the label will be data driven from an array of symbols cptSymbols[] and colors cptColors[] which form the basis of selection by data capture.

What CPTTextLayer or CPTPlotSymbol attribute can I affect do do label positioning relative to its data symbol?

Once animation starts scrolling, the newest scatter points no longer have labels!?  The sample generates a single value via timer, which sort of meets my needs - the timer that is, but I could have several points per capture.

How can I maintain the text labeling to symbol once animation starts?.

Lastly, when moving, scrolling, pinch/zoom, the display gets a bit jagged in display.

Can this be adjusted to maintain the original smooth scrolling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `labelOffset` of the plot to control the spacing between the label and the data point.

The `-dataLabelForPlot:recordIndex:` method should be called for each new data point just like the plot asks for the new data. We need to see your graph setup and datasource code to help troubleshoot further.

Drawing performance depends on many things: the hardware you're using, the number of data points, the number of different elements to draw, etc. Common things to look at are setting all unused fills and line styles to `nil` so Core Plot can skip drawing those elements, use solid colors instead of gradient or image fills, minimize the use of transparency. Also, minimize the number of grid lines and axis labels to reduce the number of elements that need to be moved and/or redrawn for each animation frame.

Comment: I added the symbol delegate; the graph datasource is the same (newData). I'm not understanding what the labelOffset - a single value; which I think is a vertical offset -horizontally it's ok. I'm trying to remedy the vertical offset.  But again the symbol labels no longer appear for new data once the graph being to scroll so eventually all I see are the symbols (small circles 16x16). Anyway, posted the relevant files and a screen shot to https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8dYf2kouuXrcVVrV3VMTklqWUE&usp=sharing

Comment: Oh I'm doing this on a 2015 15" mbPro 16/512 ssd with integrated graphics

Comment: For scatter plots, the `labelOffset` is the vertical distance between the center of the plot point and the nearest edge of the label. Positive offsets go above, negative offsets go below.

Comment: The missing labels are a bug in the labeling code. Please report it on the Core Plot [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues).

Comment: Thanks I filed it referencing the module which shows this but you can see it too in the sample once you add labels to the symbols.  As to the animation jaggies I'll have to play a bit more so I can better articulate the issue.

Comment: I couldn't get the label to position proper but instead I created an image set and filled the symbol with it using
  symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageNamed:cptTokens[index % TAG_MAXIMUM]]];
which when sized properly DOES center within the ellipsis image symbol!

Comment: p.s. I seem to have lost my symbol coloring - now all black. What attribute controls the symbol stroke coloring?

Comment: All Core Plot elements that draw lines (e.g., the border line around a plot symbol) have a line style property. You can specify the color, width, dash pattern, and more.

Comment: Duh, it appears you add a line style with color you can set into the symbol but would it be possible to have multiple fills for a symbol?  i.e., to fill with a color, then fill with an image atop the filled symbol? I'm trying to add some dynamics via color, but with a fixed marker image tag.

Comment: No. Render the whole symbol (fill, border, text, whatever) into an image and use that for the fill.

Comment: The Core Plot labeling bug mentioned above is fixed on the `release-2.2` branch.